# powershell emulate linux ls -ltr | grep string

Tags: powershell, ls

I am using this to emulate `ls -ltr | grep 'string'`. 
I cannot cut and paste from the terminal well so wanted to output to a text file.
Is there a way to output results to a text file and have that text file open immediately on desktop with all the output in the file

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\www\root\*html" | Select-String string | Select-Object -Unique Path ls -r filespec | sls pattern | select -u Path
```

I have tried `|write-output -path "C:\temp\output.txt` and some others but they are not writing.

Comment: you want to output the absolute paths of the files matching your pattern and then want to open that file with your default text editor, correct?

Comment: Maybe `| Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\output.txt"` ?

Comment: Most frequent powershell question evar.  `select -u -expand path`

Comment: `-ltr` will list the filenames (not absolute paths) line by line, sorted by modified timestamp in reverse order. Your "emulation" does not do that. So, before solving your problem to pipe your result to a file, please clarify your exact problem. Are you OK with your "emulation"? If so, you may remove it from your question and reduce the problem to how to write a string to a file and open it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to emulate the bash list and search

```
bash :::

ls -ltr /www/root/*html | grep sws 

powershell :::

.\search_html.ps1 -param1 "sws"

param( 
[parameter()]
[string] $param1 = $null ,
[string] $param2 = $null 
)


$timestr = get-date -f 'MMddHHmmss'
get-childitem -path "C:\DATA\www\root\*html" -Name | sort LastWriteTime -descending | out-file -filepath "c:\temp\lsfile$timestr.txt"
select-string -path "c:\temp\lsfile$timestr.txt" -pattern "$param1" | out-file -filepath "c:\temp\$param1$timestr.txt"
start "c:\temp\$param1$timestr.txt"
```

I open up the results in notepad - because it is so tough to cut and paste from the powershell terminal